# The perfect english whitelist cherecters reg expression php

Tags: php, regex, parsing, encoding

my problem is that i parsing lots of text paragraphs and there is always strange signs and letters in other languages.

I only need to parse the text in English.

I just want to build nice and cool reg expressions that keep only the:

1) English letters
2) numbers
3) characters on the keyboard like !@#$ etc..
4) also all the common signs like the trademark etc..
5) did i miss any characters that can appear in the text and is relevant ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume you want punctuation marks, hyphens and quotes as well (not sure if you included them in point three).

Comment: how many reg expressions you need ?

Comment: yes of-course i need all the relevant text that can be in regular English paragraph including  punctuation marks, hyphens and quotes.

i need just one regular expression. but if it is to complicated its not a problem to dived it.

Comment: what about names like Günther or Çiftçi?

Comment: good point i didnt think of. 
in that case convert the  ü->u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function (method), from [Nette Framework](http://api.nette.org/2.0/source-Utils.Strings.php.html#159):

```
/**
 * Converts to ASCII.
 * @param  string  UTF-8 encoding
 * @return string  ASCII
 */
public static function toAscii($s)
{
    $s = preg_replace('#[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\xA0-\x{2FF}\x{370}-\x{10FFFF}]#u', '', $s);
    $s = strtr($s, '`\'"^~', "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05");
    if (ICONV_IMPL === 'glibc') {
        $s = @iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1250//TRANSLIT', $s); // intentionally @
        $s = strtr($s, "\xa5\xa3\xbc\x8c\xa7\x8a\xaa\x8d\x8f\x8e\xaf\xb9\xb3\xbe\x9c\x9a\xba\x9d\x9f\x9e"
            . "\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3"
            . "\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8"
            . "\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe",
            "ALLSSSSTZZZallssstzzzRAAAALCCCEEEEIIDDNNOOOOxRUUUUYTsraaaalccceeeeiiddnnooooruuuuyt");
    } else {
        $s = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $s); // intentionally @
    }
    $s = str_replace(array('`', "'", '"', '^', '~'), '', $s);
    return strtr($s, "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05", '`\'"^~');
}
```

Comment: well, it converts all "strange" characters to English ones, keeping all the others, exactly what you have asked. For example "Žluťoučký kůň" will be converted to "Zlutoucky kun"

Comment: ...and it keeps all the other valid characters!

Comment: So i am interested if this helped?